# Show empty fields

Tags: 7, nodes, theming

I've created a custom node (node--CONTENT_TYPE.tpl.php) where I print the fields my way. For example,

```
<div class="test">
   <?PHP echo $content['field_tipsol']['#title'].":".$content['field_tipsol']['#items'][0]['value'] ?>
</div>
```

My problem is I can't see titles for the empty fields. How could I retrieve this information? It doesn't appear in $content array :(

Comment: Possible duplicate with an accepted answer: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/46161/show-fields-empty-via-render

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a var_dump of $content and see what shows up. Var_dump specifies what it's being returned even if it's boolean, empty, null, etc.