# Show fields empty via render()

Tags: 7, entities, theming

I have a content type with some fields. My client want that the empty fields must to be visible, obviously only the label. Like

```
Status: New
Owner:
Read: 714
```

I write these "fields" in my node--XYZ.tpl.php file  via

```
<? echo render($content['field_all_status']); ?>
```

But there are not "emtpy fields"

How I can set Drupal to display all fields, empty too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [Empty fields](http://drupal.org/project/empty_fields) module. I didn't use it, but look like that's the module you need.

> This module provides a way to show empty fields that would otherwise be hidden.